# Can SoapUI generate .wadl for REST projects? If yes, how?

Tags: rest, soapui, wadl

I am currently working on REST project using the [SoapUI v5.0.0](http://www.soapui.org/) Tool. The intention is to make the project's WADL (web application description languag) available on web. I would like to know if Soap UI provides facilities to generate .wadl for the REST projects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right-click on the endpoint, and select "Export WADL".